# How to properly setup/configure routing using fetch + express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm relatively new to the whole routing with express thing so please be patient with me.

I'm currently getting a 404 error in a script tag within my index.html when users fill out my form:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()   /subscribe
```

Here's my full index.html

```
HTML PORTION
-----------------------
<form action="/subscribe" method="POST">
     <div class="newsletter-form-grp">
      <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." required>
    </div>
    <button id="cta">SUBSCRIBE <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>

SCRIPT TAG AT BOTTOM
-----------------------

cta.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 
event.preventDefault();
 
let cta = document.getElementById('cta');
var email = document.getElementById('email').value.toLowerCase();
let form = document.getElementById('newsletter-form');
let success = document.getElementById('success');
let status = document.getElementById('status');
 
const regEx = new RegExp("[a-z0-8._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$");
 
console.log("Button has been clicked, starting connection to server.")
 
if (this.email.value == null || this.email.value == "") {
 
    console.log("ERROR: Connection failed, there was no email entered!");
    document.getElementById('email').value = "Hey there... you need to enter something for this to work!";
 
} else if (regEx.test(email)) {
 
    status.classList.add('fadeout');
 
    console.log("Email has been declared valid, sending data to server");

let fetchData =
   {
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify({ email: this.email.value, js: true }),
       headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
   }

console.log("Transferring data...")

fetch('/subscribe', fetchData) <- Cannot find subscribe route, returns 404 when making a post request
          .then(res => {
               if (res.ok) {
                       console.log("Data received, sending response to client", res);
                       form.classList.add('fadeout');
                       setTimeout(() => {
                              success.classList.add('fadein');
                              form.style.display = 'none';
                       }, 1000)
                              console.log("Code 200: Successful transfer!");
                            } else {
                              console.log("ERROR: Data transfer failed, sending reponse to client", res);
                            }
                        })
                }
```

Here's my app.mjs, i'm using es6 & babel.

```
//The dependenices my node js app needs (also where the require bug occurs)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import express from 'express'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install express

import request from 'request'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install request

import bodyParser from 'body-parser'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install bodyParser

import path from 'path'; //Imports the express package that we installed with npm install path

import listEndpoints from 'express-list-endpoints';

import subscribeRouter from './assets/js/routes/subscribeRoutes.mjs';
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const expressapp = express(); //Creates the application with express

const moduleURL = new URL(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(moduleURL.pathname);

expressapp.use(express.static(__dirname, {index: 'index.html'}));

//Middleware

expressapp.use(express.json()); //Tells express to use JSON as it's input

expressapp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //Encodes the URL in the body of the app's request so that they remain secure.

expressapp.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

expressapp.use('/subscribe', subscribeRouter);

console.log(listEndpoints(subscribeRouter)); // <-- Shown in console
```

Finally, my router that I configured for my subscribe route. (subscribeRoutes.mjs)

```
import express from 'express';

var subscribeRouter = express.Router();
    
subscribeRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log("Getting the subscribe route!");
})


subscribeRouter.post('/', (req, res) => { //Makes a post request to the subscribe route where req is the request and res is the response
    console.log(res);
    console.log("Post request made!");
    const { email, js } = req.body; //Create a constant that makes up of the request's body

    const mcData = { //Create a constant JSON object mcData, that contains the email from the above constant and a status message
        members: [
            {
                email_address: email,
                status: 'pending'
            }
        ]
    }

    const mcDataPost = JSON.stringify(mcData); //Turns the JSON object into a string

    const options = { //Sets a JSON object of a bunch of options that mailchimp will use
        url: 'REDACTED',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'REDACTED'
        },
        body: mcDataPost
    }

    if (email) { //If there's an email that exists
        request(options, (err, response, body) => { //Send a request to mail chimp
            if (err) { //If there's an error
                res.json({ error: err }) //Print said error
            } else { //If there's not an error
                if (js) {  //If javascript is enabled (boolean)
                    res.sendStatus(200); //Send a success message
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/success.html'); //If it's disabled, send them to a successful HTML page.
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Failed' }) //If the email doesn't exist, have it fail
    }

})
export default subscribeRouter;
```

Also if it helps, my files tree is as followed

```
public_html
  - index.html
  - app.mjs
  - assets
     - css
     - img
     - font
     - js
        - routes
             - subscribeRoutes.mjs
```

Could someone be kind enough to explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? I've been scratching my head at this one for hours.

Thanks so much for your time,

- Thomas Z

Comment: "this error" - what error? It's likely a mistake to mix client-side static files and Node files in assets.

Comment: @EstusFlask Hey there, my apologies for not making this clear enough, but the error is highlighted with the arrow in my app.mjs. I'll make an update.

Comment: the arrow in my index.html*

Comment: There's no difference for casual and conscious 404, `res.status(404)`. Make sure it's one of them. You don't need Vue to examine the problem, do requests directly and check a response.